# Issue with MongoDB Community Edition installation

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to install MongoDB by following the [official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

According to the documentation, the following command is supposed to return `OK` but I'm getting the following when I run `curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-6.0.pub | sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-6.0.gpg`:

```
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
pub   rsa4096 2022-02-23 [SC] [expires: 2027-02-22]
      39BD841E4BE5FB195A65400E6A26B1AE64C3C388
uid           MongoDB 6.0 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
```

I have read the official [troublshooting guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/installation-ubuntu-community-troubleshooting/#std-label-install-ubuntu-troubleshooting)  but I couldn't find anything related to my issue.

Comment: I used this instead from the older installation instructions, which does respond with an OK.
Not sure if this is still the way it should be done though, but it did work!
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -

Comment: Due to the `stupid rules` and `gatekeepers` here, I have to post this answer in the comments :) Try this my brother: `curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-6.0.pub |    sudo gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-6.0.gpg`

Comment: Thanks @a20, I was having the same issue. It worked with --dearmour